# Setup realurl to prevent "Bad 'L' parameter" error

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, realurl

This is an exception that is thrown when a wrong `L` parameter is present in the URL. It pollutes the typo3_log in `/typo3temp/logs/` folder.
This exception seems to be introduced with the version `2.3.0` of realurl. If I downgrade to version `2.2.1`, the error will not be logged anymore. With version `2.3.1` I also get a ***huge*** stack dump which contains the whole TypoScript configuration array.

Examples of URLs which trigger this error are:

- non integer values:

  - `https://www.example.org/index.php?uid=1&L=a`
- integers that don't match the TypoScript setup:

  - `config.linkVars = L(0-1)`
  - `https://www.example.org/index.php?uid=1&L=5`
- integers that match the TypoScript setup but don't correspond to a setup in the `realurl_config.php` file

  - `config.linkVars = L(0-6)`
  - `'preVars' => array (
     0 => array (
         'GETvar' => 'L',
         'valueMap' => array (
             'en' => '1',
             'fr' => '2',
             'es' => '3',
             'it' => '4',
         ),
         'noMatch' => 'bypass',
     ),
    )`
  - `https://www.example.org/index.php?uid=1&L=6`
- integers that don't match an existing language defined in the `sys_language` database table

The error messages are like this

> component="DmitryDulepov.Realurl.Encoder.UrlEncoder": Bad "L" parameter ("X") was detected by realurl. Page caching is disabled to prevent spreading of wrong "L" value - "*<long dump here>*"

where `X` is the wrong parameter

The long dump is not there with version `2.3.2` of realurl but with version `2.3.1`

I have a totally normal setup that worked well with version `2.2.x` of realurl like this

TypoScript

```
config.linkVars = L(0-1)
page.config.linkVars < config.linkVars
config.uniqueLinkVars = 1
config.language = de
config.locale_all = de_DE
config.htmlTag_langKey = de
config.sys_language_uid = 0

[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
config.language = en
config.locale_all = en_SUS
config.htmlTag_langKey = en
config.sys_language_uid = 1
[global]
```

realurl_conf.php

```
'preVars' => array (
    0 => array (
        'GETvar' => 'L',
        'valueMap' => array (
            'en' => '1',
        ),
        'noMatch' => 'bypass',
    ),
),
```

Activated languages English: id=1, Default Language German

I searched for the error message but all I found were some forum replies of Dimitri (the author of realurl) who claims that the configuration is wrong, but with no hint on what is being wrong.

### Note

The error is not triggered, because some links on my site have the wrong L parameter. The access log shows that those links with wrong parameters come from bots or with no referrer or from external links

Answer (score 1):

I did this patch some times ago wich seems to resolve the issue :

```
index 1ce3874..c7004ea 100644
--- a/Classes/Encoder/UrlEncoder.php
+++ b/Classes/Encoder/UrlEncoder.php
@@ -1605,10 +1605,10 @@ class UrlEncoder extends EncodeDecoderBase {
                addslashes($sysLanguageUid)
            );
            $this->tsfe->set_no_cache($message);
-           $this->logger->error($message);
-           if (version_compare(TYPO3_version, '7.6.0', '>=')) {
-               $this->logger->debug($message, debug_backtrace());
-           }
+           //$this->logger->error($message);
+           //if (version_compare(TYPO3_version, '7.6.0', '>=')) {
+           //  $this->logger->debug($message, debug_backtrace());
+           //}

            throw new InvalidLanguageParameterException($sysLanguageUid);
        }
```

I think there is nothing in the realurl configuration to fix it. So you have to apply this patch. I personally use [cweagans/composer-patches](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches) which is fine if you use composer to manage dependencies of your site.

Comment: This would only be a last resort

Comment: Otherwise, you will need to configure the Logger of TYPO3 (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/7.6/ApiOverview/Logging/Configuration/Index.html) to avoid writing of "debug" level message in production environment.